# How to determine what ports are being used when accessing a website

Tags: proxy

I'm trying to determine what ports are being used when I connect to an HTML5 client at work. We're also running guacamole and tomcat in the client. I've downloaded Fiddler and connected to the client in my browser, but I'm not very familiar with this stuff and I want to make sure I'm not missing anything. I'd like to definitively provide a client with the required ports for our service. Can someone provide a way to do this with Fiddler or suggest another method?

Thanks

Comment: You could try the answer to this question: [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/48199/1820861)

Answer (score 0):

Server side, you can use netstat to find the port in use. I use netstat -tlupn to match the port with the process. You can also use tcpdump or wireshark to inspect the trafic and find the anwser. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it via https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

You run it on client and setup your client browser to use zap as a proxy. Then once you work with the remote web application you will be able to examine in zap what ports are used.

Similar can be done via squid proxy or via simple ssh dynamic port forwarding.